# BackgroundAudioTask not working after cancelled by another app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, background-audio

When the `BackgroundAudioTask` for my app is cancelled by other app on Windows Phone 8.1 which also uses `BackgroundAudioTask`, when I go back into my app, it will no longer play audio in the background. It will play fine when the app is running but if it is suspended - the background audio also stops.

The steps to reproduce this issue are:
I launch the Windows Phone 8.1 app which has a `BackgroundAudioTask` & everything works fine. I that start another app, for example the Music player, that uses a `BackgroundAudioTask` it will cancel the `BackgroundAudioTask` of my app.

When I launch my app for the second time, I want to re-register my `BackgroundAudioTask` so that it will behave as it did originally.

In **Package.appxmanifest** I have the following:

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="WindowsPhoneBackgroundAudioTask.BackgroundAudioTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="audio" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

When I first run the application the **Run** method will be called and I add a **Deferral** to the task to make sure it is kept alive even when I close my application:

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    setupDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
}
```

When I start the music player from another application my BackgroundAudioTask **Cancelled** event is called (If I don't do `setupDeferral.Complete()` here my application will crash):

```
private void Task_Canceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
{
    setupDeferral.Complete();
}
```

When I open my app how do I recreate my `BackgroundAudioTask`? The problem is the `Run` method is never called again so I can't setup the `Deferral` again. Music will now play fine in the app, but as soon as I navigate away from the app the music will stop.

I tried manually **re-registering the task** in App.xaml.cs in the App_Resuming event with this code:

```
var taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
taskBuilder.Name = "BackgroundAudioTask";
taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(WindowsPhoneBackgroundAudioTask.BackgroundAudioTask).FullName;
BackgroundTaskRegistration task = taskBuilder.Register();
```

The above code will throw and `InvalidArgumentException` because it does not have a Trigger setup.  I don't want it to have a trigger. I just want to start the background task immediately.

Is there a way to manually instruct the OS to run the background audio again or a way to handle cancelled background audio better?

Comment: did you manage to fix this. I am having similar problems on win10 universal app

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old - but maybe someone will come across it. You actually don't need to register the task at all. 
In the case of background audio, all you need to do is call

```
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current
```

And it will fire up the task, and then your code will get the deferral.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same issue. The Background Audio Task wasn't starting playback once it was cancelled - either due to 5 minutes of inactivity, or due to another app. I was referring the sample code given by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx).

After hours of searching on the internet, I didn't find a solution. Then, digging in my code further, I found out that when the task is cancelled, the `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.CurrentState` becomes `MediaPlayerState.Closed`.

Hence, in order to restart the task/background audio playback, just set a source to the `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current` again. In the sample code, this media player object is referenced using a variable named `mediaPlayer` inside the PlaylistManager project component.

Although the sample has a piece of code to restart playback once the task is cancelled, it does not work.